# Is there a variable in Rails that equates to the template that is being rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can do request.path_parameters['controller'] and request.path_parameters['action'], but is there anything like request.path_parameters['template'] so I can discern which template file (such as index.html.erb) is being rendered?

I'm writing a method that automatically sets the body id to the template being rendered, for easy css manipulation:

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  after_filter :define_body_selector
  ...
  def define_body_selector
    # sets @body_id to the name of the template that will be rendered
    # ie. if users/index.html.erb was just rendered, @body_id gets set to "index"
    @body_id = ???
  end
  ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have different template files you could use `content_for` in them (check out [guide about layouts and templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content-for)) to set id in layout file, or just stick to `params[:action]` (it should be enough -- choice of template is based on action called).

You can make universal `before_filter` for all (or not all) actions with

```
before_filter :set_id_for_body, :only => [...]

def set_id_for_body
  @body_id = params[:action]
end
```

Always think how to keep your code DRY!

---

**EDIT:**

You could define hash that will link actions with matching templates:

```
ActionClasses = { 
  :update => "show",
  :show   => "show,
  :new    => "new",
  :edit   => "new",
  ... 
}
```

Within your layout file just add

```
<body id="<%= ActionClasses[params[:action]] %>">
```

---

**EDIT:**

It is possible to access template via `ActionBase::template` method, but it won't work the way you would like it to. If you call `filename` or `name` method in layout file, you will get path to layout file, not template. AFAIK It is impossible to check what template is being rendered, as multiple of them can be used to render single action.

Comment: thanks, samuil. but params[:action] doesn't work well because while sometimes the "show" action renders the "show" page, sometimes the "update" action renders the "show" page as well. I need a way to distinctly set the <body id=???> to the name of the template being rendered (regardless of the action).

"content_for" is a workaround that would enable me to set the body id explicitly in each template file, but requires very repetitive insertions of that line in every template file I create.

Comment: I have a slightly different case where in my case, there are couple of theme_paths added to the template resolver, and based on template availability template gets picked from theme1 or theme2 etc, and I wanted to know where it was theme2/theme1

Answer (score 0):

```
@body_id = params[:action]
```

Comment: the problem is that while sometimes the "show" action renders the "show" page, sometimes the "update" action renders the "show" page as well. I need a way to distinctly set the <body id=???> to the name of the template being rendered (regardless of the action).